# What is a good ratio of "What I want to research" vs. "My experience that shows I can research" in a Statement of purpose?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, statement-of-purpose

I am composing my statement of purpose for U.S. Graduate schools in Mathematics and am struggling to determine the proper balance of what my research plans are, and giving background in terms of independent studies, seminars, circumstances, etc. Currently, I have three paragraphs of background not available elsewhere in my application, and one explaining my plans for the future. Is this a good ratio? Should I focus more on expanding my research goals? Or do I need to have less background (One paragraph is explaining a major change)?

Comment: Unless you are confident that you are highly precocious and are indeed reasonably aiming at elite places, I'd recommend not pushing too hard on your "research plans", since almost surely you'll change your mind, to some degree, when you learn more in graduate school. These statements, whatever their names, are a subtler "test" than that, I think. It's good to have ideas and plans, but it's also good to admit open-ness to change-of-direction upon acquiring new information... which should happen hugely in grad school. People applying to grad school are not polished professionals...

Comment: @paul Thank you for your comment! So then, is it more important in a SOP to talk about your background that is not covered elsewhere? Maybe you could give me a hint as to what is being tested in a SOP, as I am at a loss.

Comment: A written narrative can cover all the myriad things that a transcript cannot possibly touch, for example. Transcripts are a very limited mirror of what happened to a person in the course of their education! Or GREs! For that matter, why are we apparently so committed to the idea that "school" is the measure of our potential for the future?!? What did you do besides get good grades? Did you _care_ about anything? :) Did you read books that weren't required? :) That kind of thing... Enthusiasm. Genuine interest.

Comment: @paul Oh! So I should spend a decent chunk dicussing things that I am intrested in, and the math I have engaged in learning on my own (taking care not to ramble)? Maybe instead of my "goals", I should talk about specific papers and programs I have spent time learning about?

Comment: Yes, I think narrative about tangible activities is infinitely better than babble about "dreams". What have you actually _done_ that is a manifestation of interest in mathematics... ? What specific things caught your fancy? What seemed unbelievably cool and compelled you to read more about it? What can you "not let go"? What do you spend your spare time reading? A chance to show non-passivity, for example.

Comment: To go along with @paulgarrett's comment, I think the most specific "research plans" I said when I applied (to top US PhD programs in math) were "I want to do algebraic geometry/number theory" (and I was more focused than a lot of people who went to top programs).

Answer (score 2):

A Statement of Purpose isn't a money-back contract stating exactly what you're going to do.  It's okay if you end up doing something different from what you imagine and write about in your admission essay.

Background information about yourself should be included as needed, so the reader can understand your account of what has been especially meaningful to you so far, and your personal motivation to go to the next level with your studies.  You don't need to write a complete catalog of everything you've done.  But do include relevant bits so that your essay hangs together as a projective story.

The admission essay is a place where you can show some inspiration.